# javascript button issue: trying to insert new record to "case"

Tags: javascript, custom-button, case, error, queue

Trying to get this button to work where right now, the error populates when status not = Approved.  The piece I am struggling with is getting a case created when stage = Approved and assigning this to a queue.  I think I am missing something in the end of the script?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/25.0/connection.js")}

var status = "{!Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c.Apttus_Proposal__Approval_Stage__c}";
var newRecords = [];

if(status == "Approved")
{
var c = new sforce.SObject("Case");
c.AccountId = "{!Account.Id}";
c.ProposalId = "{!Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c.Name}";

newRecords.push(c);

result = sforce.connection.create(newRecords);
}
else
{
alert('Quote needs to be Approved before an Order Form can be requested.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking the output of `result` and it is probably ignoring an error that is occurring when you call the `create` function.

I would guess that it is because of this line. You're attempting to set the value of an `Id` field with a `Name`.

```
c.ProposalId = "{!Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c.Name}";
```

It should probably look like this instead:

```
c.ProposalId = "{!Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c.Id}";
```

---

Revised, `ProposalId` isn't a standard field on Case, so it's missing the `__c` suffix on the field name. Two choices below depending on the type of field you've got defined on `Case` (text & lookup, respectively).

```
c.ProposalId__c = "{!Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c.Name}";
// or
c.ProposalId__c = "{!Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c.Id}";
```

Comment: Proposal_ID on the Case object is a lookup into the Proposal_Proposal__c.Name

Comment: @user38041 revised the answer with an additional observation